# Loop through lists to find a name attribute

Tags: c#, list, object, recursion, find

In C#, what is the best way to find a name of an object where it is nested in a list?

Here are my classes:

```
public class ItemListGallery
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<ItemList> ListItems { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a `List<ItemListGallery>`, and each item in the `List<ItemListGallery>` has a `List<ItemList>` and each item in the `List<ItemList>` has an `Item`, and I have a `name` value to find, how can I return the object/list with the specific `name` value?

Each name attribute is unique.

I have tried to write some find code but am lost. Is there an advanced feature of IEnumerable that I can use to help in this situation?

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the find code that I am trying to write, is this the correct approach?

```
public class ItemListGallery
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<ItemList> ListItems { get; set; }

    public string Find(string name)
    {
        foreach (var item in ListItems) 
        {
            if (item.Find(name) != null) 
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class ItemList
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }

    public string Find(string name)
    {
        foreach (var item in items) 
        {
            if (item.name != null) 
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You say you have written some code, but you have not shared it. Update the question with the missing code.

Comment: Do you want to find the ItemListGallery containing a List<ItemList> which has an item with this name? Or you want the List<ItemList> ?

Comment: is that name that you want to filter, belongs to your list or the item?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The simplest to use is LINQ.

Given a search parameter called `findStr`.  Let's assume that you want to find any `ItemListGallery` object that is named `findStr`, or contains an `ItemList` object named `findStr`, or contains an `ItemList` that contains an `Item` named `findStr`... you can do it this way:

```
var findqry = 
    (
        from gal in galleryList
        where 
            gal.name == findStr ||
            gal.ListItems.Any(li => 
                li.name == findStr || 
                li.Items.Any(i => i.name == findStr)
            )
        select gal
    );
```

If you just want a single result, `findqry.FirstOrDefault()` will give it to you.  If you want all of the results, `findqry.ToList()` or `findqry.ToArray()` will return them all.

Note that doing this in LINQ to Objects will result in case-sensitive comparisons, just like any other usage of `==` with `string`s.  LINQtoSQL on the other hand will do case-sensitive or case-insensitive compares depending on the collation of the field/table/database being compared.

If you want to do case-insensitive compares, use `string.Compare(object.name, findStr, true) == 0` or similar instead of `object.name == findstr`.

Comment: Some critique would be nice, if you're going to down-vote an answer.  Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can dot it. Either you use reflection or you use a common sub interface. **Anyway, ListItems and items should have the same name to provide some logic to the relation**.

```
public List<Item> ListItems { get; set; }

public List<ItemList> ListItems { get; set; }
```

Here is a way you can do it with a common interface

```
public interface IItem 
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IContainerItem
{
    List<IItem > ListItems { get; }
}
```

Then :

```
public class ItemListGallery : IContainerItem, IItem

..... 


public class ItemList: IContainerItem, IItem 

.....

public class Item : IItem
```

Then this is how you can retrieve it recursively :

```
private static IItem DoSearch(List<IItem> rootItems, String name) {
    foreach (var item in rootItems) { 

        if (item.Name == name){
            return item ; 
        } 

        if (item is IContainerItem) {

            var containerItem = (IContainerItem) item; 

            var result = DoSearch(containerItem .ListItems , name) ; 

            if (result != null) {
                return result ; 
            }
        }
    } 

    return null ; 
}
```